# use a name as key in R list

Tags: r

I've got this line, and I'd like to add the name of the file as key to the resulting list.

```
lapply(Sys.glob('data*'), function(file) {result = do.call("rbind", fromJSON(file=file)); mode(result) <- 'numeric'; result} )


[[1]]
<matrix>
```

should be

```
filename
<matrix>
```

Do I need another structure than a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filenames <- Sys.glob("data*")

result <- lapply(filenames, function(file) {result = do.call("rbind", fromJSON(file=file)); mode(result) <- 'numeric'; result} )

names(result) <- filenames
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set names attribute in filenames vector.

```
filenames <- Sys.glob("data*")
names(filenames) <- filenames
result <- lapply(filenames, function(file) 
                    {result = do.call("rbind", fromJSON(file=file))
                     mode(result) <- 'numeric'
                     result} )
```